# Error when trying to call xbbg in GCP using Python3.9

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, spyder, bloomberg, blpapi

I am receiving an error in response to calling `xbbg` via Cloud Functions in GCP. The code runs fine in Spyder using Python 3.9. See error below:

> Skipped: could not import 'blpapi': No module named 'blpapi'

I have tried listing both `xbbg` and the wheel file under `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Need to install `blpapi` separately (details in the installation guide). This package cannot be installed from `requirements.txt`.